# How to hide other categories in product tree if one category is selected

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Shopping cart has product category tree like

```
Category1
  Subcategory11
  Subcategory12
  ...
Category2
  Subcategory21
  Subcategory22
  ...
Category3
  Subcategory31
  Subcategory32
  ...
```

It is placed in left side of screen.
Initially it is shown in collapsed form

Screenshot1:

```
Toggle show all categories
Category1
Category2
Category3
```

User can open some node by click. In this case (for example clicking in Category2) other categories should be removed from screen so that only this category and its subcategories are visible:

Screenshot2:

```
Toggle show all categories
Category2
  Subcategory21
  Subcategory22
```

`Toggle show all categories` link should toggle single category and category list views: first time click should show collapsed category list again like in Screenshot1. After that clicking in `Toggle show all categories` again should show only last opened category like in Screenshot2.
This is implemented in http://www.officeday.ee/Buroo-pohitoovahendid/

How to implement this ? Is there some jquery or jquery-ui plugin or can jqgrid customzed for that ?

All trees which I have found leave main category list also visible if some category is selected like

```
Category1
Category2
  Subcategory21
  Subcategory22
Category3
```

It is required that Category1 and Category3 disappear if Category2 is selected like shown in Screenshot2

ASP.NET/Mono MVC2, jquery, jquery-ui and jqgrid treegrid are used currently. jquery-ui and jqgrid can replaced to something other if this leads to solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a common class for categories for example `.hidden` and `commonClass`

```
hidden{display:none}

$('.category').click(function(){
 $(this).css('display','block')
 $('.commonclass').addClass('hidden')

});
```

somthing like this you can try...

Comment: This hides active category also. How to keep active category visible?